Vue 3 apollo client UseLazyQuery for multiple results
I am trying to run the useLazyQuery in my vue to get data from Apollo client. I am passing the parameter and query return different results based on the parameter being passed.
My issue is that result become false after the first load which is mentioned on Apollo docs:
load(document?, variables?, options?): function to start querying. Returns Promise<Result> if it is the first time the query is called, false otherwise.

I want to be able to reload the data every the parameter is change or load() function is called. My code below:
const iqConfigSettingsFolder = computed(
    () =>
      '/sitecore/content/ABC/BCD/Settings/Config Settings Folder/' +
      configCategory.value +
      '/' +
      configSettingName.value
  );
  const { load, refetch } = useLazyQuery(
    configSettingsQuery,
    {
      path: iqConfigSettingsFolder, //data changes based on path change
    },
    { fetchPolicy: 'no-cache' }
  );

  const getSetting = async (
    settingName: string,
    settingCategory: SettingCategory
  ): Promise<string | number | boolean | undefined> => {
    configCategory.value = settingCategory;
    configSettingName.value = settingName;
    let result = await load(); //this one returns false after first run
    if (!result) {
      result = await refetch(); //this one returns the same results after every run
    }
    const setting = result?.item?.fields?.filter((x: any) => x.name == 'Value')[0]?.value;
    if (setting) {
      const isBool = setting.toLowerCase() == 'true' || setting.toLowerCase() == 'false';

      if (isBool) return toBool(setting);
      if (parseFloat(setting)) return toNumber(setting);
      return setting;
    }
    return;
  };


If I understand correctly, you want to call the getSetting() everytime the variable iqConfigSettingsFolder changes. I would use a Watcher.
watch(iqConfigSettingsFolder,async (newPath, oldPath) => {
    await getSetting(configSettingName.value, configCategory.value);
  },
  { immediate: true } // Trigger on initialization
);

